# Size of stringstream

Tags: c++

Is there any direct way to calculate size of internal string in stringstream?

Here, `str()` returns a copy and then it gets the size of string.

```
std::stringstream oss("String");
oss.str().size();
```

Comment: The word size doesn't make sense for stream, shouldn't it be no. of bytes in stream?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

```
std::stringstream oss("String");
oss.seekp(0, ios::end);
stringstream::pos_type offset = oss.tellp();
```

This is for the write pointer, but the result is the same for read pointer on Visual C++ v10.

Comment: no. of bytes would be offset * sizeof(wchat_t)? in case of wide char stream?

Comment: @Mayur No, the `tellp()` returns a size in bytes, not character. If you wanted the size in character you'd do the opposite (`offset / sizeof(wchar_t)`).

Answer (score 63):

There is:

```
std::stringstream oss("Foo");
oss.seekg(0, ios::end);
int size = oss.tellg();
```

Now, **size** will contain the size (in bytes) of the string.

EDIT:

This is also a good idea to put after the above snippet as it puts the internal pointer back to the beginning of the string.

```
oss.seekg(0, ios::beg);
```

Comment: Interesting.  I wonder if this will always show the same result as the write pointer equivalents.

Comment: If you use the write pointer, would you still need to seek to the end? Wouldn't it always be at the end?

Comment: Gcc 4.4 does not seem to like this, it sets the stream failbit

Comment: Some simple usability would be nice. Not that the solution isn't easy, but still it's pretty ugly.  Kind of hard to believe there isn't a size() convenience function. :)And

Comment: On a more serious note, it is important to mind your p's and g's, put and get pointers.  That is, one example uses seekg() and tellg() while the other uses seekp() and tellp().  Both work but don't mix them.

Comment: And one more thing: whichever pointer is disturbed should be put back to where it was, not necessarily the beginning.  A no-side-effect implementation would grab the pointer location before changing it: int loc0 = oss.tellg(); and then reset it afterwards:  oss.seekg(loc0, ios::beg);